# How to pass Html partial to the Custom directive's attribute in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and part of learning i am stuck here.
I have a custom directive on element level and it has a isolated scope attribute called Route which is assigned to a string and i am broadcasting it to another directive's controller like when ever i click on element it is navigating to another directive's template area and displaying the route message so which is working good so far and now i want to replace that string with a HTML Partial.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

```js
//Directive
"use strict";
angular.module('adminMenuModule').directive('adminMenuItem',function(){
 return{
  
 require: '^adminMenu',
  scope:{
   label:'@',
   route :'@'
  },
  templateUrl: 'adminMenu/adminMenuItemTemplate.html',
   link: function(scope, el , attr,ctrl){
    scope.isActive = function(){
     return el === ctrl.getActiveElement();
    };
    el.on('click', function(evt){
     evt.stopPropagation();
     evt.preventDefault();
     scope.$apply(function(){
      ctrl.setActiveElement(el);
      ctrl.setRoute(scope.route);
     });
    });
    
   }
  
 };
});
```

```html
<!--Main admin Page-->
<admin-menu-item label="Employee Management" route="employee"></admin-menu-item>

<!-- Directive's template-->
<li class="admin-selectable-item ">
 <div class="admin-noselect">{{label}}</div> <i
 class="fa fa-2x fa-caret-left admin-menu-active-indicator"
 ng-if="isActive()"></i>
</li>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to modify an asp.net Html.Partial on the fly? Or are you wanting to modify the HTML of a target directive? I'm unsure of being able to do the former as Html.Partial is rendered by the server. If you mean the latter, could you explain? Angular has a strict contextual escaping service to aid with on-the-fly HTML processing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I am looking to change target directive template where i want to include another partial  As of now i am just displaying route string which i am listening from source directive.